# Is all-caps blackletter no longer taboo?

Tags: typefaces, trends, calligraphy, type-theory, blackletter

Received typographic wisdom holds that blackletter (“Old English”, “Gothic”) text only looks good in lower case or with initial capitalization — never with capital letters in series. However, in the last couple of decades, all-caps blackletter type and calligraphy have become normalized in a few cases where reading speed is unimportant. Specifically, decoration in "cholo" gangster culture and album cover artwork have adopted it, often in laid out in the shape of an arch; examples follow.

Apparently, some designers are doing what was previously forbidden. In light of the cover of the record by No Doubt (a major-label band), has all-caps blackletter gone mainstream? Did breaking the old rule lead to a new understanding?

[image: Teen Angels magazine cover]
[image: Dark Funeral band logo]
[image: "Barragán" tattoo]
[image: No Doubt album cover]

Comment: It's a counter-culture, rebellious "look." Some like it, some don't. It's a personal choice. Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: The only taboo in design is bad taste

Comment: I find most of those impressively hard to read. If your goal is low legibility then go for it. The only upside to choosing such low legibility is that **IF** someone spends enough time reading it then their vested time would translate into remembering what the text says without the need to actually read it in the future.

Comment: What does that tattoo say, anyway? Looks like "Barragan" to me, which means the person is likely getting their own named tattooed on themselves and is that _really_ someone you want to emulate?

Comment: @MikeTheLiar Definitely.

Comment: @SFinSF: Where are you seeing an "r" in the first word?  Teen Angel's was an indie magazine back in the 80s

Comment: @SFinSF In addition to what krb said, Teen Angel was the pseudonym of the creator of "Teen Angel's". It is supposed to be possessive, not plural.

Comment: "Does it do its job? Did the message get through to the intended audience". It is the only possible definition of good design - Malcolm Garrett

Answer (score 40):

1. You *can't* use tattoo art as a reference. Tattoo art *often* fails to follow any rhyme or reasoning. It's *always* a one-off and created with the intention of a very narrow audience, not broader viewing. (And there's always someone at hand to immediately say: "No, it says xxxx.")
2. Bad design happens. There's no "Global Design Tribunal" which determines what one must or must not do with respect to design and will punish offenders. – The "Dark Funeral" logo/symbol falls into this to me. It was probably created by one of the band members or their friend who has no formal training and just wanted something which "looks evil". So, they thought that "looked evil". Black metal bands are *notorious* for horrid type design. I think it is unwise to prescribe traditional training thoughts or guidelines to *anything* related to music industry or band "logos". They are *rarely* created by trained designers.
3. Sometimes it may be *intentional*. The No Doubt album, with it's poor blown-out photo, and bad typography all seem very intentional to me to avoid a "slick" record industry look. Sometimes when bands which are seen as more alternative start bordering upon being seen as "selling out" they go *specifically* the other direction with design and stage productions to try and curb those comments.

None of this means all cap blackletter is a *good* choice in general – or a *common* choice. It's merely a choice they made in your samples.

Comment: For there to be good design there has to be bad design ;)

Comment: Ironically, the Dark Funeral logo is one of the most recognizable logos in black metal. It has a unique silhouette, relevant imagery, does not depend on colour and is _actually legible_! Unprecedented stuff in the BM community.

Comment: @Gusdor As somebody seeing it for the first time, it took me several seconds to parse "funeral", letter by letter, reading like a four-year-old. I guess that's technically "legible", in about the same way that [your least favourite fast food place] is technically "food".

Comment: @DavidRicherby its highly possible that I have simply become aclimatised to truely horrific logos like Dark Throne and Ingested.

Comment: @Gusdor In terms of legibility, I probably wouldn't have even guessed there were letters in Ingested's logo without the context of these comments.

Comment: `:)` *"Black metal bands are notorious for horrid type design."* `:)`

Comment: @Gusdor Dark Funeral was one of the first Black Metal bands, and their logo was created before the current trend of illegibility being a _feature_ for a metal logo.

Comment: @DarrickHerwehe This is just a nitpick but...Dark Funeral wasn't anywhere near being one of the first BM bands. That font was probably popularized by Bathory, with the rest of the logo most likely inspired by Venom. By the time Dark Funeral was around, illegibility was popular in black metal to some extent as well as death metal

Comment: @popctrl While I see your point that some bands were formed in the 80s, the scene really picked up in the early 90s (especially 91). Since Dark Funeral was formed in 93, and it's now over 25 years later, I still consider them an early influencer to the genre.

Comment: @popctrl You're right, some Bathory cover art would have been perfect here.

Answer (score 18):

> Received typographic wisdom holds that Blackletter ("Old English", "Gothic") text only looks good in lower case or with initial capitalization — never with capital letters in series

If you ask me (and all sources I have ever read about the matter), the problem is not that all-caps blackletter does not look good. It just is very difficult to read due to the various decorative elements.

Therefore if you do not care about readability that for whatever reason, using all-caps blackletter is at least not completely insane:

- All your examples feature titles, logos, or similar. It is only one or two words that are difficult to read, and they are usually not meant to be read at all. In particular consider the tattoo: It mostly exists to please the wearer (and he has to use two mirrors to see it). Everybody else who gets to see it probably has enough time to decipher it.
- One historic use of all-caps blackletter was for printer’s locations on titles, such as here:

  [image: all-caps blackletter used for location on a title]
  <sup>([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Basel_2012-10-06_Batch_Part_5_(44).JPG))</sup>

  [image: all-caps blackletter used for location on a title]

  Again, this is not a case where readability is very important.
- Another historic use of all-caps blackletter was for God, Jesus, etc. in religious texts:

  [image: Example of “GOTT” (God) and “JESU” in all-caps in a German text]

  [image: Example of “JESOM” (God) in all-caps in a Sorbian text]

  I think we can safely assume that the authors/typesetters of these texts would not have chosen all-caps here if they considered it ugly. Also, given that this is limited to a very few, usually isolated words, the impact of readability is not big.

Comment: At least your “religious text” examples, and I think also your “printers mark” examples, come from documents using blackletter for their main body text, and are from cultures/times when readers were accustomed to blackletter as the standard script for printed text.  As such, they don’t really tell us anything about the perception of blackletter *today*, either in aesthetics or readability.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine: *As such, they don’t really tell us anything about the perception of blackletter* today, *either in aesthetics or readability.* – Yes, but the “received typographic wisdom” against all-caps blackletter on which the question is based is similarly old. What I am showing is that it was never as strict as the asker perceives it.

Comment: Just because you and I find it hard to read doesn't mean that the original intended audience found it hard to read. And perhaps the intent was to slow down your reading at the words you were supposed to focus on?

Comment: @MichaelKay: I don’t have any sources at hand right now, but readability was generally cited as a reason against blackletter all caps. Also, for whatever it’s worth, I can read blackletter fluently (see my profile as to why), and I still struggle with blackletter all caps. Finally, while there are typographic reasons that all-caps blackletter is difficult to read, readability is also a chicken–egg problem: You can read easily what you are used to. And given the scarcity of all-caps blackletter in printed work from that time, I think it’s safe to assume that readers weren’t used to it.

Comment: Fascinating article linked from your profile. People have some weird hobbies. I'll content myself with getting better at reading the stuff.

Comment: Your examples are in Fraktur, which is a different style from the "Old English" in the OP. For differences, see e.g. S and the crossbar of A.

Comment: @RosieF: Yes, but it is still blackletter (which is what was asked for). Also, I don’t think that this affects the conclusion that much as the arguments against all-caps blackletter are the same.